# How to dynamically replace the value of ngCspNonce in Angular hosted on Azure

Tags: angular, azure, content-security-policy

I have an Angular 14 application hosted in Azure.  I am implementing the Content Security Policy in the app.  I don't want to use 'unsafe-inline' to load third party inline styles.  I followed this link in Angular's website https://angular.io/guide/security#content-security-policy but I am not sure what I have to do in Azure to replace the value of ngCspNonce attribute before Azure serves the index.html to user.  Any help would be appreciated.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

To replace the value of the `ngCspNonce` attribute before Azure serves the `index.html` to users. You can modify the Angular application build process to inject the nonce value directly into the `index.html` during the build phase.

Here's how you can achieve that:
**index.html**

```
<!doctype  html>
<html  lang="en">
<head>
<meta  charset="utf-8">
<title>Your Angular App</title>  
<meta  http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline';">
<script>
window.__nonce__ = '{{ nonceValue }}';
</script>
</head>
<body>
<app-root></app-root>
</body>
</html>
```

In your Angular app's code (e.g., `app.component.ts`), you can generate the nonce value dynamically and bind it to the `nonceValue` property:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  title = 'dynamicNonce';
  nonceValue!: string;

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.nonceValue = this.generateRandomNonce();
  }

  private generateRandomNonce(): string {
    const charset = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789';
    const nonceLength = 16;
    let result = '';

    for (let i = 0; i < nonceLength; i++) {
      const randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * charset.length);
      result += charset.charAt(randomIndex);
    }

    return result;
  }
}
```

Here's the full content of the `src/app/app.component.html` file with the provided `<div>` element using the `nonceValue`
attribute binding to set the nonce value dynamically, which allows the execution of scripts according to the Content Security Policy (CSP) of your application.:

```
<div  [attr.ngCspNonce]="nonceValue">
<!-- Your app content here -->
<h1>Welcome to My Angular App!</h1>
<p>This is a sample content.</p>
<p>Nonce Value: {{ nonceValue }}</p>  <!-- Display the nonce value -->
</div>
```

**Deploy your Code to a Webapp:**

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  In index.html you have `<script>
window.__nonce__ = '{{ nonceValue }}';
</script>`.  But here I want to replace the value of ngCspNonce attribute.  How would I do that?  I am not sure why you have window.__nonce__ there.  According to Angular documentation I have to replace the value in two places.  1. `<app ngCspNonce=**????**></app>` 2. In the metatag `<meta  http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src **nonce_value_here**">`